# Zero-knowledge composability

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Suppose a protocol *P* is composed of two different zero-knowledge protocols. Can we assume *P* is also zero-knowledge?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe give an example.

Comment: In particular, it should be good to define "composed".